# Are there any ways to obtain the line number of the matched pattern line?

Tags: bash

For example , A text file has:

```
dfsdfsd
f
dsf
dsf
dsf
dsf
sdafadfdasfdsfd
sf
sdfasdfdasfdsfsdf
sd
fsdfdsaf
```

Then , i would like to find a way to obtain the line number of sf
and insert a paragraph before sf

Are there any ways to doing it in bash programming ???thanks

Comment: do you want to do it manually replacement, something using `vi` ?

Comment: `grep -n` gives you line numbers of matched patterns…

Comment: sed seems the most appropriate way. I get a string and insert it before the matched pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out the line number, you could use `grep -n`.

If you just want to insert a line on the preceding line, you could use `sed` like this:

```
sed "s/sd/paragraph\nsd/" file
```

This will insert the text "paragraph" above the line with "sd".

To only do this for the first match:

```
sed "0,/sd/ { s/sd/paragraph\nsd/ }" file
```

Here, we only match lines until the first matching "sd", so any later sd's will not match.

Comment: Thanks. But what will it happen if there are more than one sd?? I only want to insert before the first sd

Comment: Ah, then it gets more complicated :) I added to my answer, did that help?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` has [more commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) than just `s///`. To insert text before each matching line:

```
sed '/pattern/ i \
text to be \
inserted goes \
here'
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a regex replace, replacing `\nsf\n` with `\n\nsf\n`, or something similar depending on your specific requirements. Doesn't get you the actual line number, but if all you want to do is insert a paragraph, that may not be necessary.