# How to use sed to insert in a line before the matching pattern

Tags: bash

I am dealing with some html code and i got stucked in some problem. Here is the extract of some code and the format is exactly the same

```
                                                        <tr>
                          <td nowrap valign="top" class="table_1row"><a name="d071301" id="d071301"></a>13-Jul-2011</td>
                          <td width="21%" valign="top" class="table_1row"><a href="http://www.info.htm" target="_blank">LCQ8: Personal data of job</a></td>
```

Here i have to match with

```
                                                    <tr>
                      <td nowrap valign="top"
```

and insert something before `<tr>` .the problem occurs as i have to match a pattern in different lines. 
i have tried

```
grep -c "<tr>\n<td nowrap valign="top"" test.html
grep -c "<tr>\n*<td nowrap valign="top"" test.html
grep -c "<tr>*<td nowrap valign="top"" test.html
```

to test but none of them works.So i have two dimension to figure out the problem:

> 1. Match `<td nowrap valign="top" and insert in the line above`
> 2. Match whole string

```
                                                <tr>
                  <td nowrap valign="top"
```

Would anyone suggest a way to doing it in either way?

Comment: [Hope this similar question i raised before can help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624199/how-can-i-append-a-string-into-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pattern

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6732702/7552

Answer (score 2):

Using sed you can perfom replacement on multiple lines. Its also easy to substitute the match.

```
sed  "/\s*<tr>\s*/ { N; s/.*<tr>\n\s*<td.*/insertion\n&/ }"
```

This cryptic line basically say:

1. match a line with  (`/\s*<tr>\s*/`)
2. continue on next line (`N`)
3. substitute the matched pattern whit the insertion and the matched string, where & represent the matched string (`s/.*<tr>\n\s*td.*/insertion\n&/`)

Sed is very powerful to perform substitution, its a nice to know tool. See this manual if you want to learn more about sed:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `grep -P "tr>\s*\n\s*<td"`.
2. It's not clear how it will help you to insert something before `<tr>`, but anyway.
3. Quoted strings do not nest, you need to escape the quote characters, or use single quotes instead of double quotes.